# Entity Framework doesn't implement interface member for View

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created a view and added it to my Model via "Update model from database". Model validates, but as soon as I add that new View into Interface, it throws error on compile:

> Error 4   'Entities.Model.TestEntities' does not implement interface
>   member 'Entities.Interfaces.ITestEntities.CustomerWinningsView'

Which is very interesting, since when I add normal table member it works with no problems.

```
public interface ITestEntities
{
DbSet<Browser> Browsers { get; set; } - normal table works
DbSet<CustomerWinningsView> CustomerWinningsView { get; set; } - view throws error on compile..
}
```

Context:

```
public partial class TestEntities : DbContext, ITestEntities
{
    public TestEntities()
        : base("name=TestEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<Browser> Browsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerWinningsView> CustomerWinningsViews { get; set; }
}
```

Do I have to set something additional for views in EF?

Comment: Where is the implementation?

Comment: EF automatically generates the code. Check the updated post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interface defines

```
DbSet<CustomerWinningsView> CustomerWinningsView { get; set; }
```

Yet your `DbContext` implements

```
public DbSet<CustomerWinningsView> CustomerWinningsViews { get; set; }
```

Change either interface or implementation method to match eachother. (`CustomerWinningsView` or `CustomerWinningsViews`). If as you say both were code generated, it might be a bug in the pluralization mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, need glasses I guess.

Comment: Probably just a long day :-)